# Jenkins fail to run xml

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, testng

i am using TestNG, Maven and java. When running my automated tests through eclipse they run normally, but when i try to run them through Jenkins it is simply displayed this error below:

```
    **C:\Users\user\git\Projeto\Projeto>java org.testng.TestNG** 
    **C:\Users\user\git\Projeto\Projeto\JenkinsXml\Mainframe.xml**  
    **[TestNG] Running:**    
    **C:\Users\user\git\Projeto\Projeto\JenkinsXml\Mainframe.xml**
    **===============================================**  
    **Extent Parallel Test**
    **Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0**
    **===============================================**   
    **Build step 'Executar no comando do Windows' marked build as failure**
    **Finished: FAILURE**
```

This is not a very helpful error, what turns it even difficult...

**.bat archive used:**
call C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\git\Projeto\Projeto\ScriptBat\JenkinsConfigWorkspace\ScriptConfig.bat
cd %projectLocation%
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\JenkinsXml\Mainframe.xml

**.xml archive used:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Extent Parallel Test" parallel="classes"
 thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
 <parameter name="dispositivo" value="Android Emulator" />
 <parameter name="versaoAplicativo" value="3" />
 <parameter name="browserParametro" value="Chrome" />

 <parameter name="baseURL" value="https://portal/login.jsp" />  

 <parameter name="caminhoPlanilha" value=".\caminho\nomePlanilha.xlsm" />

 <test name="Macro" allow-return-values="true">
  <parameter name="executavel" value="mainframe.edp" />  
  <parameter name="nomeMacro" value="RecuperarDadosMainframe" />
  <classes>
   <class name="mobile.android.empresa.automacao_massas.RunExcelMacro" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

I would like to make it clear that this xml calls a java class that calls a mainframe app. I am able to run the xml through cmd but not able to run the batch that calls this xml.

Comment: Why not try adding `verbose="2"` (or a higher value) to your `<suite>` tag in your `testng.xml` and try again ? This will cause TestNG to start dumping stacktrace on the console and that should give you an indication of what was the failure and perhaps help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnanMahadevan i will try this..

Comment: Please do post back what you find.

Comment: I have add the verbose to the suite, it really worked on eclipse, but in Jenkins unfortunately there wasn't any difference.

Comment: Today I changed the commands I was using to run the batch file in cmd and I had a different error on cmd...:  

[TestNG] [Error] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:1; columnNumber:1; The content is not allowed in the prolog

Comment: That last error ("content is not allowed in the prolog") usually means your xml is invalid, maybe there's something before <?xml?>.

Comment: Yes @MikeHarris, i am searching about it and i found this too, but what i can't understand is why the xml does run in cmd if i run it directly, but doesn't if i run it through the batch file.
I have already copy and past it in a notepad, but i could not find any different character..

Comment: Ok, today even not finding any invalid character i copied the text of the xml file and pasted it in a txt file. I deleted the xml file and i saved the txt file as xml in my project. Then i had the error:   
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Invoke of: Open

Comment: After that i made this two folders:   

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop and 

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop   

And i am having this error now:  

com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: Save     |    

until now i did not find any solution to that....

Comment: So, i am still not able to run the batch through cmd but now Jenkins is calling and executing the xml but giving this error. I didn't find any solution until now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! unfortunatelly it is still not runing in cmd, but my goal was to run in Jenkins and now it is running.
What I did were all the steps in the comments above and also configured my jacob jar in the classpath. I didn't imported just the jar but its whole folder, because that way the dll files could also be imported. 
To access the classpath in eclipse go:
Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables

I hope this can help someone...

Comment: It would be more helpful if you'd summarize the steps here instead of having people dig through all these comments...